# export mysql table to csv file using batch script

Tags: mysql, batch-file

I am trying to export mysql table data to csv file using batch file.
It works on the screen but not able to ouptut to a csv file.

```
 @echo off
    " C:\ProgramFiles\MYSQL\MYSQL Workbench 6.3 CE\mysql.exe" mysql -uroot -ppassword -e "select plate form SWP;" > \output.csv
    pause
    exit
```

Comment: `\output.csv`wierd path looks to me as a invalid windows path. Use more something like `C:/output.cvs`

Comment: tried that but gives me options  and  its syntax

Comment: maybe it should also be in double qoutes.

Comment: Thanks  yes that was  silly of me. Worked Thanks

Comment: @RaymondNijland, the "weird" path `\output.csv` points to the file `output.csv` in the current drive; it is valid, but might be unintended; using `C:/output.csv` is not recommended (though it might work) as the Windows path separator is `\ `...

Comment: Since the problem seems to be caused by a simple typo, this question should be deleted in my opinion, because it is not going to help other users...

Comment: @aschipfl learned something new i wasn't really into batch programming. But  "`\output.csv` points to the file output.csv in the current drive" i think it points to the applications current working directory not drive and the file `output.csv`..

Comment: @RaymondNijland, to explicitly point to the current working directory, you would need to specify `.\output.csv`, which is equivalent to `output.csv`...

Comment: Youve already used `mysql` which is generally a shorthand version of the fully qualified path to `mysql.exe`, so don't use it again. Also I'd assume you should be `select`ing `from`, _not `form`_ i.e. `@"%ProgramFiles%\MYSQL\MYSQL Workbench 6.3 CE\mysql.exe" -uroot -ppassword -e "select plate from SWP;" >"output.csv"`.

Answer (score 1):

mysql got a feature for this :  LOAD DATA INFILE
This will load the content of a query in a file.

Check the doc here :

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html