# Export MySQL Table to CSV file through Batch File

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I need to export my MySQL tables to CSV files with a batch file. Is there any option like that?

I am getting many ETL references in Google search, but is there any command line arguments, which can be used in batch file so that I can export the data in CSV format with headers?

There is an URL [export mysql table to csv file using batch script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51248473/export-mysql-table-to-csv-file-using-batch-script) regarding this, but not clear, what to write in the batch file.

Can anyone please help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM firstdb.user
INTO OUTFILE 'C:/ProgramData/MySQL/MySQL Server 8.0/Uploads/employee_backup.csv'   
FIELDS ENCLOSED BY '"'   
TERMINATED BY ';'   
ESCAPED BY '"'   
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n';
```

Comment: thank you, it worked, can I add headers as well in that CSV?